# jQuery : Hide a parent based on child property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a HTML Page (sample)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="first">
<label>First</label>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
</div>

<div id="second">
<label>Second</label>
<input type="checkbox">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It shows two checkboxes as shown below

[image]

I would like to know if it is possible via jQuery to hide only the second checkbox.

The actual page which I am working on contains about 40 checkboxes and I would like the solution to be applicable even for that also.

Is it possible ?

Can someone let me know how to do this ?

Comment: what is the condition to hide the checkbox?

Comment: . . . and what is the condition to unhide the checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `:not()` selector with `:checked` to select the unchecked checkbox
2. Use closest to get the parent div then use `.hide()`

```js
$('.anchor:not(:checked)').closest('.container').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first" class='container'>
  <label>First</label>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class='anchor'>
</div>

<div id="second" class='container'>
  <label>Second</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class='anchor'>
</div>
```